# effect of a and b in a hyperbolic paraboloid

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

quite new in using this platform so I hope I'm doing it the right way.

I'm taking Pre-Calculus right now, and I'm trying to understand how some equations affect the resulting plot. As far as I understand in a hyperbolic paraboloid the horizontal traces are hyperbolas and the vertical traces are parabolas, so, given the equation:

$$ z = \frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} + k $$

$k$ represents the displacement in the $z$-axis, but I quite don't get it when talking about $a$ and $b$, what's the effect when they are changed? What if $a$ is greater than $b$ or $b$ greater than $a$?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: They'll represent stretches in the $x$ and $y$ directions. It helps to start by just picking some values and seeing what happens. Start by plugging in $k = 0$ and $b = 1$, and analyze what happens as you modify $a$, then set $a = 1$ and vary $b$. It could also be helpful to think about slices, say through $y=0$ or $x=0$. Then, you can focus on what happens to cross-sections, and it might be easier to visualize.